# How To Optimize Method Merging Two Hashes [RUBY]

Tags: arrays, ruby, optimization, hash

I have constructed a method that merges two hashes where one of their keys values are the same. The method can be seen below:

```
  def self.hash_merge_on_location(base, additions_arr, location)
    base.each_with_index { |b_hash,b_index|
      additions_arr.each do |addition|
        addition.each_with_index { |a_hash,a_index|
          if b_hash[location] == a_hash[location]
            base[b_index] = b_hash.merge(a_hash)
          end
        }
      end 
    }   
    base
  end
```

So my question is how can I make this method better? Right now I have base (array of hashes), additions_arr (array of array of hashes), and location (key to compare) as my parameters and I iterate over over hash in my base array and then compare this against every array of hashes in my additions_arr. I finally check to see if the current hash value in my array in my additions_arr is equal to the hash value in my base array.

An example would be as follows:

**Base Array**

```
[{"loan_number" => 10808, "spec_type" => "New"}, 
 {"loan_number" => 10809, "spec_type" => "Old"}]
```

**Additions Array**

```
[
 [{"loan_number" => 10808, "new_field" => 10}, 
  {"loan_number" => 12383, "new_field" => 19}],
 [{"loan_number" => 10809, "new_field" => 11}]
]
```

So right now with my current code with a location input of "loan_number" the output of hash_merge_on_location would be:

**Output**

```
[{"loan_number" => 10808, "spec_type" => "New", "new_field" => 10},
 {"loan_number" => 10809, "spec_type" => "Old", "new_field" => 11}]
```

Is there anyway in which I can optimize my method as it stands currently? Or anything else I could do to make it better?

Comment: Index your base array by location so you dont need to iterate all the array for each change in additions

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this or point me to a resource? Thanks for the help

Comment: Create a new hash called index. Iterate over base array and put a key (location) in index with a reference (or index of array if ruby has no references) to the base array element. Then iterate over additions, and you can find the base array element with that location using index[location]

Comment: So when you say put a key in index as location do you mean the actual value like in my case Index would be {10808=>0}. So that the location value points to the index in the base array?

Comment: Indeed :). {10808=>0, 10809 => 1}

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You need to state in words, at the outset, what your code is intended to do.  It has something to do with merging hashes that have a common key, but that is not enough. You are forcing readers to try to figure out your objective from your code, which if off-putting and no doubt is the reason no answers have been posted to date. Also, as links tend to break over time it's generally not a good idea to use them (e.g., "Run code snippet") as you have. Instead, just show the return value for each example string. If readers want to copy your code they can simply cut-and-paste.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will make sure to do so going forward